# is there a scripting solution for determining the default application path for a file on the Mac?

Tags: bash, macos

For a given extension, for example ".psd", I'd like to be able to determine the default application path for opening this file, for example "/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS4.app".

I've looked into the Launch Services API, and there are clearly programmatic ways to get this information.  Unfortunately for my particular scenario, only a scripting solution (Applescript or shell script) will do.

I've also looked at "lsregister -dump".  It seems to be unwise to rely on parsing this information, since there are no guarantees as to the stability of the output format.

I've been solving this problem in the past with Creator Codes, but since Apple seems to be phasing them out since Snow Leopard I'm trying to eliminate dependence on Creator Codes.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Launch Services is the one and only place to get that information. You can write a scripting addition that will expose its functionality to AppleScript, but then you have to install that on whatever machine you plan to run on.

System Events does give you this in Leopard
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091222-eessetxeqbai2mnwduygtm1cd5.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091222-eessetxeqbai2mnwduygtm1cd5.png)